# Unable to get Traefik working with Visual Studio and Service Fabric

Tags: traefik

I have been following the document here to get Traefik working with Service Fabric

https://github.com/jjcollinge/traefik-on-service-fabric/blob/master/Docs/Deployments/VisualStudio.MD

I have followed the instructions exactly but keep on getting errors with Traefik application, see image.

[image: error1]

[image: error]

As you can see, I have an application working fine, called Voting, but can't get Traefik to work.

Has anyone seen this type of error?

Regards

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Enable log redirection for the Traefik service. This is documented here: https://github.com/jjcollinge/traefik-on-service-fabric#debugging

If you get logs, then it's Traefik that is crashing and you should be able to see the issue there.

If you don't get logs, then Service Fabric is unable to start the Traefik process. This is usually due to port contention on the local machine. Is there anything else running on port 80 or are you trying to run multiple instance of the Traefik service?